# Using [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost()] for web UI testing

Tags: asp.net, .net, selenium, web-testing, webdev.webserver

I have a WebApp project that runs normally in debugging. Now I try to run it for UI testing with Selenium:

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost(@"D:\WebAppPath", "/")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:28319/")]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

And the test fails with the error:

> The Web request '`http://localhost:28319/`' completed successfully
>   without running the test. This can occur when configuring the Web
>   application for testing fails (an ASP.NET server error occurs when
>   processing the request), or when no ASP.NET page is executed (the URL
>   may point to an HTML page, a Web service, or a directory listing).
>   Running tests in ASP.NET requires the URL to resolve to an ASP.NET
>   page and for the page to execute properly up to the Load event. The
>   response from the request is stored in the file
>   'WebRequestResponse_TestMethod1.html' with the test results; typically
>   this file can be opened with a Web browser to view its contents.

Can I use `AspNetDevelopmentServerHost` for HTTP hosting, not for unit testing? Is there any other way to programmatically host ASP.NET application (without running external iisexpress.exe process)?